# What does this Xamarin Profiler value mean?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monogame

I'm using the Xamarin Profiler for the first time. I want to check how much memory is used by my application(iOS). What does "Max 49 MB" mean? Is this the memory that my application is using right now? What is the difference between memory allocated(5,8 MB) and "Max 49 MB"?

In addition, the value(49 MB) slowly increases every few seconds. But my application is not changing its state, my application just draws one sprite all the time. Why is the value increasing all the time?
I'm testing the application on my iPhone device.

Profiler screenshot: [Profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojxyy.png)

Answer (score 0):

"Memory allocated" includes allocations size that may not be in use (but that they have been) during all profiler session.Max value refers to Working set: "working set" basically is the current physical memory being used, it may include non managed memory. working set is a perf counter. therefore, the working set includes the memory allocated + native memory -currently used-

cheers